# JSON Completion Handler

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, xcode

This is the code I am currently using:

```
func fetchOne(){
        URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:apiURL!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            do {
                let allContactsData = try Data(contentsOf: self.apiURL!)
                let allContacts = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allContactsData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
                if let arrJSON = allContacts["data"] as? [[String : Any]] {
                    for aObject in arrJSON {
                        self.followerUsername.append(aObject["username"] as! String)
                        self.followerFullName.append(aObject["full_name"] as! String)
                    }
                }
//                print(self.followerUsername)
//                print(self.followerFullName)

            } catch let error as NSError {
                print(error)
            }
        }).resume()
    }
```

How can I detect when the json has finished fetching all the info in **data** and then run a new function `fetchTwo()` ?

Comment: Just put `fetchTwo()` where you have the commented out `print` statements?

Comment: If you want synchronous then you can call the next one inside fetchOne, or you could use a semaphore. Otherwise, I'd suggest using a notification to broadcast it and trigger fetchTwo in the observer.

Comment: @smarx So, no matter if it's going to be 100 or 10000 elements/strings in the `username`, it will still run when it is all finished?

Comment: @CanJoe Yes. Why don't you try it and see?

Comment: @smarx I could, but this is using a Instagram API, so it only allows me to fetch 10 users :) Can also give Rashwan L's answer a try.

Answer (score 1):

If your method is **asynchronous** then you can add a `completionHandler` to you function, like this:

```
func fetchOne(onCompletion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void, onError: @escaping (NSError) -> Void) {
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:apiURL!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        do {
            let allContactsData = try Data(contentsOf: self.apiURL!)
            let allContacts = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allContactsData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
            if let arrJSON = allContacts["data"] as? [[String : Any]] {
                for aObject in arrJSON {
                    self.followerUsername.append(aObject["username"] as! String)
                    self.followerFullName.append(aObject["full_name"] as! String)
                }
                onCompletion(true)
            }
//                print(self.followerUsername)
//                print(self.followerFullName)

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
            onError(error)
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

Usage:

```
fetchOne(onCompletion: { (successful) in
    print(successful)
    fetchTwo()
}) { (error) in
    print(error.domain)
}
```

If it´s **synchronous** then just do this:

```
func fetchOne(){
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with:apiURL!, completionHandler: {(data, response, error) in
        guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
        do {
            let allContactsData = try Data(contentsOf: self.apiURL!)
            let allContacts = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: allContactsData, options: JSONSerialization.ReadingOptions.allowFragments) as! [String : AnyObject]
            if let arrJSON = allContacts["data"] as? [[String : Any]] {
                for aObject in arrJSON {
                    self.followerUsername.append(aObject["username"] as! String)
                    self.followerFullName.append(aObject["full_name"] as! String)
                }
            }
//                print(self.followerUsername)
//                print(self.followerFullName)
                  fetchTwo()

        } catch let error as NSError {
            print(error)
        }
    }).resume()
}
```

**Update:**

```
fetchOne(onCompletion: { (successful) in
    print(successful) // fetch one
    fetchTwo(onCompletion: { (successful) in
        print(successful) // fetch two
    }) { (error) in
        print(error.domain)
    }
}) { (error) in
    print(error.domain)
}
```

Comment: How do I know it it's **asynchronous** or **synchronous**?

Comment: `URLSession.shared.dataTask` should be async.

Comment: Never used this before. Interesting. Where exactly do I put the **Usage:** code.

Comment: Where you call `fetchOne` today, replace that call with the **usage** code.

Comment: Is it also possible to do this with three different functions? After fetchOne, run fetchTwo, and after fetchTwo, run fetchThree?

Comment: The `fetchTwo()` doesn't work, error: `Missing argument for parameter "onCompletion" in call`. My fetchTwo func code starts like this: `func fetchTwo(onCompletion: @escaping (Bool) -> Void, onError: @escaping (NSError) -> Void) {`.

Comment: You need to call it the same way as you´re calling `fetchOne` check the provided usage example.

Comment: I am talking about the `fetchTwo()` inside `fetchOne(onCompletion ...`. It wont let me run it. You can see images here: https://i.imgur.com/fYmROAZ.png and here: https://i.imgur.com/M0hDJU7.png .

Comment: @CanJoe, as I said you must call it the same way as you called `fetchOne`. Check the update and see how I mean.

Comment: Is this better then using `DispatchGroup`?

Comment: For this purpose in my opinion yes.

Comment: How come exactly? Sorry, I'm trying to learn. What will the difference be?

Comment: You should use `DispatchGroup` when you make an iteration and you want to wait for each async call to finish before you go to the next iteration. Use the `completionHandler` when you want to have a callback for a function as you have.

Comment: But isn't that what I want? I want to wait until both `fetchOne` and `fetchTwo` are finish, and then run `fetchThree` ? Shouldn't I be using `DispatchGroup ` then?

Comment: By iteration I mean `for i in 0..<10`. You can do as I wrote in my update. That´s how I would have done it. Up to you what you want to do.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Swift :)

You are mixing synchronous and asynchronous code together.

When you call login you expect it to return an answer straight away of type [String : String].

But in your login method you then do a network call which can not return straight away...which is why the call to Alamofire.requesttakes a completion block as a parameter.

So...you need to change your login method so it:

does not return anything straight away (it can not do so...logging in requires us doing a network call remember)
takes a completion block to invoke once login has succeeded.
This can be done like so:

```
public func login(userName: String, password: String, loginCompletion: @escaping ([String : String]) -> ())
```

Welcome to Swift :)

You are mixing synchronous and asynchronous code together.

When you call login you expect it to return an answer straight away of type [String : String].

But in your login method you then do a network call which can not return straight away...which is why the call to Alamofire.requesttakes a completion block as a parameter.

So...you need to change your login method so it:

does not return anything straight away (it can not do so...logging in requires us doing a network call remember)
takes a completion block to invoke once login has succeeded.
This can be done like so:

public func login(userName: String, password: String, loginCompletion: @escaping ([String : String]) -> ())
Here we have a function that takes a userName of type String, a password of type String and a loginCompletion of type function that again takes a [String : String] dictionary as a parameter. Notice that the method does not return anything.

Now you can call your makeWebServiceCall almost as before:

```
let loginrequest = JsonRequests.loginRequest(userName: userName, password: password)
makeWebServiceCall(urlAddress: URL, requestMethod: .post, params: loginrequest, completion: { (JSON : Any) in
   //Now we are ready, the login call has returned some data to you. 

   //You have an attribute named JSON of type Any, which you need to convert to [String : String], and then you can call loginCompletion with that, like so:
   loginCompletion(yourConvertedDictionaryHere)
})
```

Here is the new login method in its completeness:

```
public func login(userName: String, password: String, loginCompletion: @escaping ([String : String]) -> ()) {
    let loginrequest = JsonRequests.loginRequest(userName: userName, password: password)
    makeWebServiceCall(urlAddress: URL, requestMethod: .post, params: loginrequest, completion: { (JSON : Any) in
       //Now we are ready, the login call has returned some data to you. 

       //You have an attribute named JSON of type Any, which you need to convert to [String : String], and then you can call loginCompletion with that, like so:
       loginCompletion(yourConvertedDictionaryHere)
    })
}
```

Welcome to Swift :)

You are mixing synchronous and asynchronous code together.

When you call login you expect it to return an answer straight away of type [String : String].

But in your login method you then do a network call which can not return straight away...which is why the call to Alamofire.requesttakes a completion block as a parameter.

So...you need to change your login method so it:

does not return anything straight away (it can not do so...logging in requires us doing a network call remember)
takes a completion block to invoke once login has succeeded.
This can be done like so:

public func login(userName: String, password: String, loginCompletion: @escaping ([String : String]) -> ())
Here we have a function that takes a userName of type String, a password of type String and a loginCompletion of type function that again takes a [String : String] dictionary as a parameter. Notice that the method does not return anything.

Now you can call your makeWebServiceCall almost as before:

let loginrequest = JsonRequests.loginRequest(userName: userName, password: password)
makeWebServiceCall(urlAddress: URL, requestMethod: .post, params: loginrequest, completion: { (JSON : Any) in
   //Now we are ready, the login call has returned some data to you.

//You have an attribute named JSON of type Any, which you need to convert to [String : String], and then you can call loginCompletion with that, like so:
   loginCompletion(yourConvertedDictionaryHere)
})
Here is the new login method in its completeness:

public func login(userName: String, password: String, loginCompletion: @escaping ([String : String]) -> ()) {
    let loginrequest = JsonRequests.loginRequest(userName: userName, password: password)
    makeWebServiceCall(urlAddress: URL, requestMethod: .post, params: loginrequest, completion: { (JSON : Any) in
       //Now we are ready, the login call has returned some data to you.

```
   //You have an attribute named JSON of type Any, which you need to convert to [String : String], and then you can call loginCompletion with that, like so:
   loginCompletion(yourConvertedDictionaryHere)
})
```

}
And then you call your login method like so:

```
retur.login(userName: "root", password: "admin01") { stringDictionary: [String : String] in
    //here you have your stringDictionary which you can use as pleased
}
```

Hope that helps you.